# Play sound in arbitrary channel

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio, avaudioplayer, nssound

**(OSX/Cocoa)**

I need to be able to take any sound (or sounds) from a collection of sound files and play it (or them) through an arbitrary sound output channel, preferably with per-sound level control and more-or-less automatic channel mixing. (meaning that multiple sounds can play simultaneously in the same channel)

**The sound must be capable of being looped cleanly.**

The available output channels would be *in addition to* the default built-in audio, added via USB audio devices. For the purposes of this question a "channel" is equivalent to a USB Audio adapter.

In other words, I need to find/write something like:

```
 -(BOOL) [someObject playContentsOfURL: (NSURL) soundURL  
                            viaChannel: (id) channelspec
                         atVolumeLevel: (double) volume
                                  loop: (BOOL) loop
         ];
```

**AVAudioPlayer** is very close, but it appears to *assume the use of the built-in stereo audio*. I cannot figure out how to route the output to a particular output device. **It loops great, however**.

**NSSound**'s **playbackDeviceIdentifier** does the output device routing part, but NSSound's looping is *terrible*. If NSSounds looping wasn't so lousy, it would be a winner.

So if you have an answer for **making NSSound loop cleanly**, that would answer this question very satisfactorily.

If you can specify **how to provide output routing to AVAudioPlayer**, that would be equally nifty.

**OR**, if you can point to or provide CoreAudio or other code that will accomplish this, that could work also.